# SQL: MAX like implementation of OR on Grouped object

Tags: sql-server, group-by, linq-to-sql, max

I have a table `Example` like this:

```
Id, Type, Flags(in integer)
1,   A,    8 (B1000)
2,   A,    7 (B0111)
3,   B,    3 (B0011)
```

The Flags are stored as integer, but interpreted as Binary.
When I group by Type to get the MAX of each Type, I do it like this:

```
SELECT Type, MAX(Flags)
FROM Example
GROUP BY Type
```

What can I do to get the Logical OR of all the values in a Group of Flags? 
eg: what I want is this:

```
Type, ResultFlags
A,    15 (B1111 = B1000 | B0111)
B,    3 (B0011)
```

Is there a way to do this in a `GROUP BY` clause or any other way which isn't too costly?

I am also curious how you can do this in LINQ to SQL.

Comment: do you want sum of Flags filed(8+7=15)?

Comment: `SELECT Type, BIT_OR(Flags) FROM Example GROUP BY Type`

Comment: @Tushar not the sum, but the logical OR
B1010 | B1101 should give me B1111, not B10111

Comment: @Nick I need it for sql server. `BIT_OR` works for mysql only.

Comment: @Omkar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981050/aggregate-bitwise-or-in-a-subquery