# Aggregate bitwise-OR in a subquery *with partitioning*?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, aggregation, sql-server-2019

I've been looking at how to do a bitwise-OR aggregation in TSQL in a subquery, and the answers given in a [popular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981050/aggregate-bitwise-or-in-a-subquery) don't seem to maintain partitioning.  Is there any way for me to partition?

Let's say we have the following data:

```
id | someCount | someFlags
1  | 2         | 0
1  | 3         | 2
1  | 0         | 1
2  | 1         | 4
2  | 5         | 0
2  | 1         | 1
```

I can get the `SUM` of the `someCount` field partitioned by `id` *without losing any of the original rows* like so:

```
SELECT [testSum] = SUM([someCount]) OVER (PARTITION BY [id]) FROM myTable
```

Is there a way to do this with a bitwise OR operation? so I'd get:

```
id | value
1  | 3
1  | 3
1  | 3
2  | 5
2  | 5
2  | 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be as below. Extend it out to the number of bit positions that you care about.

Having to repeat the `PARTITION BY [id]` is a bit tedious but I would expect SQL Server to only do the partitioning work once and calculate all the `MAX`  expressions inside the same aggregate operator.

```
SELECT *, 
        MAX(someFlags & 1) OVER (PARTITION BY [id])  +
        MAX(someFlags & 2) OVER (PARTITION BY [id])  +
        MAX(someFlags & 4) OVER (PARTITION BY [id])  +
        MAX(someFlags & 8) OVER (PARTITION BY [id])
FROM (VALUES
(1 , 2 , 0),
(1 , 3 , 2),
(1 , 0 , 1),
(2 , 1 , 4),
(2 , 5 , 0),
(2 , 1 , 1)
)V(id ,someCount ,someFlags)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 DECLARE @MyTable TABLE( ID int, SomeCount int, SomeFlags int)
INSERT INTO @MyTable
    VALUES
            (1, 2, 0)
        ,   (1, 3, 2)
        ,   (1, 0, 1)
        ,   (2, 1, 4)
        ,   (2, 5, 0)
        ,   (2, 1, 1)
;

WITH SumTable   AS 
    (
        SELECT 
                iD
            ,   TestSum     =   SUM(SomeCount)
            ,   BitOrSum    =   SUM(SomeCount | SomeFlags)
        FROM @MyTable
        GROUP BY ID
    )

SELECT  
        T.ID
    ,   S.TestSum
    ,   S.BitOrSum
FROM    @MyTable    T
JOIN    SumTable    S   ON  S.ID = T.ID
ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: This returns `6` and `11` for `BitOrSum` - not the correct `3` and `5`

Comment: That's correct. For ID=1: 2 or 0=2; 3 or 2 = 3; 0 or 1=1. SUM(2,3,1)=6

Comment: Perhaps you just want the TestSum, which is a simple SUM of SomeCount. This is the only field that gives you the desired result, but there is no Bitwise-OR involved/needed in that calculation.

Comment: The desired results are from bitwise or ing all the values in the partition. I.e. select 0|2|1, 4|0|1